# Finding eigenvalues and complexity of calculating determinant vs reducing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, computational-complexity

I was given the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -4 & 4\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and told to try and "guess" it's eigenvalues. This is my first problem - I don't see how to guess them by mere inspection. Is there an easy way?

What I did do is notice we can quickly reduce it to
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -4 & 4\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and read off the eigenvalues of the diagonal. This seems to take much less work than calculating $\det(\lambda I-A)$, so I was wondering whether "on average" reducing and taking determinant have the same "complexity"...

Comment: I think the point of the "guessing" is that the second row has only a $2$ in it, so getting rid of the $1$s underneath it isn't going to affect the other two pivots, so you can essentially read off the eigenvalues. You'd have a hard time guessing the eigenvalues of something like

\begin{pmatrix}
1 &4 &5 &7\\
2 &5 &2 &8\\
9 &3 &1 &8\\
2 &7 &3 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}

because you've got a lot more to do than eliminate some $1$s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful because performing row operations on $A$ does not preserve the eigenvalues of $A$ since row operations correspond to changing $A$ to $PA$ for some invertible $P$ there is no reason that $PA$ will be similar to $A$ in general. For example, the eigenvalues of

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

are $\lambda = 0,2$ but if we perform one row operation $R_2 = R_2 - R_1$ we get the matrix

$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} $$

whose eigenvalues are $\lambda = 0, 1$.

I'm not sure what is considered "guessing" but in your case, the matrix $A - \lambda I$ has the form

$$ A - \lambda I = \begin{pmatrix}1 - \lambda & 0 & -4 & 4\\
0 & 2 - \lambda & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 - \lambda & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 - \lambda \end{pmatrix}. $$

and so it is clear that by performing column and then row expansion we get $\det(A - \lambda I) = (1 - \lambda)^3(2 - \lambda)$ and so the eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 2$.